# Difference between AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter vs WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Whats are the difference between these classes? I know that WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is used to customize "security" on our apps.

**Whats I've done:**

```
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

@Autowired
private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;
```

But i don't understand the meaning of AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter.

I read a couple of articles but I don't get it.

Comment: Do you use OAuth2? What do you not understand? What do you already understand? Which articles did you read?

Comment: yep im using oauth. i dont understand the purpose of authorizationserverconfigureradapter

Answer (score 33):

One thing first. OAuth 2 is an authorization framework. It allows an  application (client) to obtain limited access to a HTTP service on behalf of a resource owner (user). OAuth 2 is not an authentication protocol.

**AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter** is used to configure **how the OAuth authorization server works**.

Here are some aspects which can be configured:

- supported grant types (e.g. authorization code grant)
- authorization code service, to store authorization codes
- token store, to store access and refresh tokens (e.g. JwtTokenStore)
- client details service, which holds the client configurations
- ...

**WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter** is used to configure **how the OAuth authorization server is secured**.

Or in other words, how the user has to authenticate to grant a client access to his resources.

This can be:

- form authentication
- authentication via an identity provider (Facebook Login)
- ...

(I have intentionally omitted some details to keep the answer as simple as possible.)

---

Example authorization server configuration with an in-memory token store:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore());
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new InMemoryTokenStore();
    }

    ...

}
```

Example security configuration with form login:

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/oauth/authorize").authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin();
    }

    ...

}
```

Comment: Very simple explanation. Good one.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use a third party authenticater, this means at the same time OAuth, then you must use AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter with WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter at OAuth serverside. If not so, WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is enough for ordinary authentication